# How do I export UUID from my Drupal user database into javascript on a single page?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, drupal

I am completely new to drupal and still struggling with the structure (also I have no experience in PHP, I've mostly worked with C and matlab ealier).

I am writing a page that makes calls/queries (using javascript) to parse.com, this works as long as I manually enter the UUID. How can I get it from the drupal-database (MySQL) to my webpage/javascript the easiest way?

Please tell me if I left out important stuff, I am an engineer and have done quite a bit of programming, but never any web-development so I know very little about all this.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have connected your JS file and you use Drupal behavior:

So to send a php variable value to js you need:

```
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('my_var' => $my_var)), 'setting');
```

and to access it in JavaScript:

```
 Drupal.behaviors.example_behavior = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

      // Check if the variable exist.
      var dSettings = Drupal.settings;
      if (dSettings.myModule != undefined) {         
        x = (dSettings.myModule != undefined) ? dSettings.myModule.my_var : ''; 
        if (terms.length && x != '') {  
        // Variable exist.   
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

[Source](http://cornel.co/article/check-if-variable-exist-js-sent-through-php/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, hower I  don't think I have "connected [my] JS file and use Drupal behavior". As I am not comfortable at all with Drupal I have just created a basic page, and written all the JS within <script> tags. Where would I write the drupal_add_js(.... ) line? Thank you.